# How to solve this integral equation?

Tags: numerical-analysis-of-pde, integration

$$g(p) = \frac{1}{p^3} + \frac{2}{p^2} \int_{p}^{1}{(u-p)g(u)du}$$

Need to find $g(p)$ for $p > 0$.

If there is no explicit solution, how to solve it numerically? Maple13 calculates bad results, even worse than my own programming implementation (but it yields larger error).

Example: $g(0.5) \approx 10.14122941$

Comment: Multiply by $p^2$, differentiate twice and rewrite as $p(pg')' + 3pg' + g = 2/p^3$, with $g(1)=1, g'(1)=-3$. This is a [Cauchy-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)-type equation, for which you can find exact solutions.

Comment: Alternatively, let $f(p) = \int_p^1 (u-p) g(u) du$. Find $g$ in terms of $f$, and this is an inhomogeneous linear differential equation in $f$ (and one that turns out to be easy to solve, if you chose the "nice" relationship).